# Change Error message of Struts token resubmission action page error

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, token

```xml
<action name="manual_order" class="materialTypeMasterAction" method="enquiry_process">
    <interceptor-ref name="token"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref> 
    
    <result name="success">/pages/procurement/EnquiryDetails.jsp</result>
    <result name="invalid.token">/pages/procurement/EnquiryDetails.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

I would like to change this `invalid.token` error message. Where can I change that message.

Answer (score 0):

The message resource keys for `invalid.token` are

```
struts.messages.invalid.token=The form has already been processed or no token was supplied, please try again.
struts.internal.invalid.token=Form token {0} does not match the session token {1}.
```

You can use this message keys to change the `invalid.token` messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of `struts.messages` in struts [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.0.14/org/apache/struts2/struts-messages.properties). Only modify the `struts-messages.properties`.

```
struts.messages.invalid.token=The form has already been processed or no token was supplied, please try again.
struts.internal.invalid.token=Form token {0} does not match the session token {1}.
```